# Kernel freeze : How to debug it?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, freeze

I have an embedded board with a kernel module of thousands of lines which freeze on random and complexe use case with random time. What are the solution for me to try to debug it ?

I have already try magic System Request but it does not work. I guess that the explanation is that I am in a loop or a deadlock in a code where hardware interrupt is disable ?

Thanks,
Eva.

Answer (score 10):

Typically, embedded boards have a [*watch dog*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/watchdog).  You should enable this timer and use the [`watchdog`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) user process to kick the *watch dog* hard ware.  Use `nice` on the `watchdog` process so that higher priority tasks must relinquish the CPU.  This gives clues as to the issue.  If the device does not reset with a *watch dog* active, then it maybe that only the *network* or *serial port* has stopped communicating.  Ie, the kernel has not locked up.  The issue is that there is no user visible activity.  The *watch dog* is also useful if/when this type of issue occurs in the field.

For a *kernel lockup* case, the [lockup watchdogs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/lockup-watchdogs.txt) kernel features maybe useful.  This will work if you have an infinite loop/deadlock as speculated.  However, if this is custom hardware, it is also possible that **SDRAM** or a *peripheral device* latches up and causes abnormal *bus* activity.  This will stop the CPU from fetching proper *code*; obviously, it is tough for *Linux* to recover from this.

You can combine the watchdog with some *fallow memory* that is used as a *trace buffer*. `memmap=` and `mem=` can limit the memory used by the kernel.  A driver/device using this memory can be written that saves *trace points* that survive a reboot.  The *fallow memory's* ring buffer is dumped when a *watchdog* reset is detected on kernel boot.

It is also useful to register thread [notifiers](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/notifier.h) that can do a `printk` on context switches, if the issue is repeatable or to discover how to make the event repeatable.  Once you determine a sequence of events that leads to the lockup, you can use the *scope* or *logic analyzer* to do some final diagnosis.  Or, it maybe evident which peripheral is the issue at this point.

You may also set `panic=-1` and `reboot=...` on the kernel command line.  The [**kdump**](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kdump/kdump.txt) facilities are useful, if you only have a code problem.

Related: [kernel trap (at web archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120324053437/http://kerneltrap.org/node/6452). This link may no longer be available, but aren't important to this answer.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. I know that my board handles hardware watchdog feature. I will try this to confirm that is a lockup case. I also try to use SLUB/SLAB debug by adding slub_debug=FZPU in my kernel arguments. Then when I run slabinfo -v to validate all my slab, no output. So I guess that slab debug does not detect error in  kobject memory. I also try to enable in kernel configure : CONFIG_DETECT_SOFTLOCKUP. But no change, I am always freezing. So lets try watchdog this time...