# Kernel panic error in ARM board

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have ARM board at remote location. Some time I had a kernel panic error in it. At this same time there is no option to hardware restart. bus no one is available at this place to restart it.

I want to restart my board automatically after kernel panic error. so what to do in kernel.

Answer (score 2):

If your hardware contains [watchdog timer](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0190a/ar01s02s16.html), then compile the kernel with watchdog support and configure it. I suggest to follow this blog http://www.jann.cc/2013/02/02/linux_watchdog.html

**Caution** :: I never tried this. If the problem is solved, request you to update here.

Comment: Thank you for reply, This your and is right but not working on my board.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the panic() function kernel/panic.c to call the kernel_restart(*cmd) at the point you want it to restart (like probably after printing the required debug information).

I am assuming you are bringing up a board, so Please note that you need to supply the ops for the associated functions in machine_restart() - (called by kernel_restart) in accordance to the MACH . If you are just using the board as is , then i guess rebuilding the kernel with kernel_restart(*cmd) should do.

Comment: I don't think you need to modify `panic()`.  `panic()` will call `kernel_restart()` and the `arm_pm_restart` hook will get called.  So, you can just modify your machine file to keep your changes locale.

Answer (score 2):

The `panic()` is usually due to events that the kernel can not recover from. If you do not have a watchdog, you need to look at your hardware to see if a **GPIO**, etc is connected to the **RESET** line. If so, you can toggle this pin to reboot the CPU. Trying to alter `panic()` may just make things worse, depending on the root cause and the type of features you use.

You may hook [`arm_pm_restart`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/process.c#n127) with your custom restart functionality.  You can test it with the shell command `reboot`, if present.  `panic()` should call the same routine. <sup>With current ARM Linux versions</sup>

You may wish to turn off the MMU and block interrupts in this routine.  It will make it more resilient when called from `panic()`.  As you are going to reset, you can copy the routine to any physical address you like.

The *watchdog* maybe better; it may catch cases where even `panic()` may not be called.  You may have a *watchdog* and not realize it.  Many Cortex-A CPUs, have one built in.  It is fairly rare for hardware not to have a watchdog.

However, if you don't have the *watchdog*, you can use the GPIO mechanism above; hardware should usually provide someway for software to restart the device (and peripherals).  The `panic()` maybe due to some mis-behaving device tromping memory, latched up DRAM/Flash, etc.  Toggling a **RESET** line maybe better than a *watchdog* in this case; if the **RESET** is also connected to other hardware, besides the CPU.

Related: [How to debug kernel freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255334/kernel-freeze-how-to-debug-it), [How to change watchdog timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402865/how-to-change-the-watchdog-timer-in-linux-embedded)

Comment: Having both is the most fault tolerant.  Ie, a *watchdog* and an `arm_pm_restart` hook that hits a hardware **RESET** line; hopefully the line has a latch or hold up as the CPU may not hold it when it is resetting.  If you have absolutely no hardware support, you can try to place the CPU in a reset configuration (all the CP15 registers) and jump through the reset vector in whatever boot code you have.  Hook this routine via `arm_pm_restart`.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, a simple way to restart the board after kernel panic is to pass a kernel parameter (from the bootloader usually)

```
 panic=1
```

The board will then auto-reboot '1' second(s) after a panic.

Search the [Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) for more.

Some examples from the documentation:

```
...
panic=      [KNL] Kernel behaviour on panic: delay <timeout>
            timeout > 0: seconds before rebooting
            timeout = 0: wait forever
            timeout < 0: reboot immediately
            Format: <timeout>
...
oops=panic  Always panic on oopses. Default is to just kill the
            process, but there is a small probability of
            deadlocking the machine.
            This will also cause panics on machine check exceptions.
            Useful together with panic=30 to trigger a reboot.
...
```

Comment: Right, but his issue is that `panic` does not reset his board?  Ie, the `panic` functionality is not working.  This is how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in previous comments watchdog timer is your friend here. If your hardware contains watchdog timer, Enable it in kernel option and configure it.

Other alternative is use [Phidget](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/Main_Page). If you usb connection available at remote location. Phidget controller/software is used to control your board using USB. Check for board support.